# React hook not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I have a hook named "note" where I have the state set to create a object. This object gets loaded with some filler information when I first create a card and then that information gets loaded into "addNote" which creates a new note and saves it in an array of notes. When I want to pull that note back up, it runs showCard which is where the card is supposed to be retrieved and loaded back into the form. See below

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [showCreate, setCreate] = useState(false);
  const [note, setNote] = useState({});
  let currentNote = {};

  function toggleCreateCard() {
    setCreate(oldCreate => !oldCreate);
  }
  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }
  function createNewCard(newItem) {
    setNote({
      header: newItem,
      content: "",
      checklist: [],
      pictures: [],
      dueDate: "",
      comments: []
    });
    toggleCreateCard();
  }
  function showCard(id) {
    currentNote = notes[id];
    setNote(currentNote);
    toggleCreateCard();
  }
```

The problem I'm having is that the let "currentNote" properly pulls up the note from the notes array. However, when I try to update the note state, it doesn't load the title correctly. It seems to retain the last state of "note" when the process of creating the card was started.

The top is an example of the object that should be loaded in the hook, and the bottom is an example of what actually gets loaded in the hook

`index.js:27 {header: "test", content: "test1234 test1234 test1234 test1234 test1234 test1…234 test1234 test1234 test1234 test1234 test1234 ", checklist: Array(2), pictures: Array(0), dueDate: "", …}`

`index.js:27 {header: "test", content: "", checklist: Array(0), pictures: Array(0), dueDate: "", …}`

How do I get the note state to update correctly?

EDIT 1 (additional information): the "createNewCard" and "showCard" functions are being called by two components below:

```
<Body
        noteList={notes}
        removeCard={deleteNote}
        submitNote={addNote}
        showCard={showCard}
      />
      {showCreate ? (
        <CreateCard
          note={note}
          addNote={addNote}
          createOff={toggleCreateCard}
        />
```

Generally note is specifically being loaded for "CreateCard" component which calls on this and includes subcomponents for the individual form fields to make it more readable

```
  const [loadNote, setNote] = useState({
    header: props.note.header,
    content: props.note.content,
    checklist: props.note.checklist,
    pictures: props.note.pictures,
    dueDate: props.note.dueDate,
    comments: []
  });
  function handleChange(event) {
    setNote(prevNote => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [event.name]: event.value
      };
    });
  }

  function submitNote() {
    props.addNote(loadNote);
    props.createOff();
  }
  return (
    <form
      className="create-card form-styling shadow-15px lato"
      onKeyPress={e => {
        e.key === "Enter" && e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <Title header={loadNote.header} update={handleChange} />
      <Description description={loadNote.content} update={handleChange} />
      <Checklist checklist={loadNote.checklist} update={handleChange} />
      <Pictures pictures={loadNote.pictures} update={handleChange} />
      <DueDate duedate={loadNote.dueDate} update={handleChange} />
      <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" size="small" onClick={submitNote}>
        <AddIcon />
      </Fab>
    </form>
  );
```

The entire project is on code sandbox right now if more details are needed https://codesandbox.io/s/ideaboard-listing-tool-n0je5?file=/src/components/App.jsx:1263-1539

Comment: Hi, what are you passing to id, in showCard? id. Are you trying to reference the array by index. Also where are you logging note, setNote is an async method.

Comment: yes, I'm passing in the index for id in showCard. as for loggin note I set up console.logs for after "currentNote = notes[id];" for the first example and 
"setNote(currentNote);" for the second example. What actually is displayed in the card right now is just whatever the title for the object in the Notes array even if note has the given example, but right now I'm trying to figure out why I can't get note to update correctly

Comment: Right, so the line after setNote, note doesn't have the value yet. This blog post talks aobut the hooks being async and how to work around that, maybe that helps: https://sung.codes/blog/2018/12/07/setting-react-hooks-states-in-a-sync-like-manner/

Comment: Ciao, you have to add more code to understand better  your problem. Who calls `createNewCard`, `showCard` and `addNote`?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I added more details and link to the entire code sandbox if more is needed beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

So I apparently was running around in circles chasing my own tail. The data itself was in fact already going to the card, I just did not have the correct property names being called on so I was only getting my title of the card and no other information. All of this trying to console log the data going into the card was moot because of that. I still cannot say I understand the async functionality, but at least I am getting the data in